# Display hyperlinked text

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to display the value of a hyperlinked text into another cell. For example, I have a column that contains several hyperlinks each linked to a specific cell in other sheets. What I would like is that whenever someone clicks on the hyperlink that value (text) will display in another cell on my main sheet.

I've tried to enter a VBA for getUrL but that was giving me the result I was looking for. Let me know if anyone is able to provide a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using the Private Sub Worksheet function FollowHyperlink (i.e. VBA code in the worksheet) as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Sheets("MainSheet").Range("E2").Value = Selection.Value
    Sheets("MainSheet").Range("E3").Value = Target.SubAddress
    Sheets("MainSheet").Range("E4").Value = Target.Range
End Sub
```

[image]